# CakePHP content count in breadcrumbs

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am using cakephp breadcrumbs helper , I have breadcrumbs template

```
$this->Breadcrumbs->setTemplates([
                'wrapper' => '<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                                <ol {{attrs}}> {{content}}
                                </ol>
                              </nav>',
                'item' => '<li  {{attrs}}>
                                <a itemprop="item" href="{{url}}"{{innerAttrs}}>
                                <span>{{title}}</span></a> 
                                <meta content={{count}}> 
                           </li>{{separator}}',
]);
```

In meta content I need count like 1,2,3...

My present Output

```
<nav>
   <ol>
      <li>
          <a href=""></a>
          <meta itemprop = "position" content>
      </li>

   </ol>
</nav>
```

Desire output :

```
<nav>
       <ol>
          <li>
              <a href=""></a>
              <meta itemprop = "position" content=1>  <-- desire output 
          </li>
    
       </ol>
    </nav>
```

I am able to do it by JavaScript. Is it possible to place list count dynamically in meta content (`<meta content={{count}}`> ) using cakephp breadcrumbs helper ?

Comment: Your question is not easy to understand, explain what exactly you want to count, and what does breadcrumbs have to do with metadata?

Comment: @Salines I want to count list, I need this for google SEO 
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb#microdata

I need the position of list according to google suggested breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[CakePHP Book: Customizing the Output](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/breadcrumbs.html#customizing-the-output)**

```
$this->Breadcrumbs->add(
    'Products',
    ['controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'index'],
    [
        'class' => 'products-crumb',
        'data-foo' => 'bar',
        'count' => 1 //<----------------------------
        'innerAttrs' => [
            'class' => 'inner-products-crumb',
            'id' => 'the-products-crumb'
        ]
    ]
);

// Based on the default template, this will render the following HTML:
<li class="products-crumb" data-foo="bar">
    <a href="/products/index" class="inner-products-crumb" id="the-products-crumb">Products</a>
    <meta itemprop = "position" content=1>  <-- desire output

</li>
```